# Nginx: Prevent direct access to static files

Tags: nginx

I've been searching for a while now but didn't manage to find anything that fits my needs. I don't need hotlinking protection, as much as I'd like to prevent people from directly accessing my files. Let's say:

My `website.com` requests `website.com/assets/custom.js`, that'd work,but I'd like visitors which directly visit this file to get a `403 status code` or something. I really have no idea if it's possible, and I don't have any logical steps in mind..

Regards !

Comment: Show your nginx config (part `server { server_name website.com ...}`)

Comment: @mr_tron it is very very simple , the default config, it's a static subdomain so it has a `root` and a `server_name` !

Comment: I don\`t fully understand what do you want. You have some static file without dynamic generating content (for example: `index.html, main.css and logo.png`) and want that people can load files `main.css` and `logo.png` only if they open index.html in browser and this file try get `main.css` and `logo.png`?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be able to see the "logo.png" file through the `index.html` but not by directly accessing `static/logo.png`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use nginx referer module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html.
Something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
    root /var/www/website.com/html ;
    location /assets/ {
        valid_referers website.com/ website.com/index.html website.com/some_other_good_page.html ;
        if ($invalid_referer) {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

This config guard `assets` directory. But remember, that not guaranteed and worked only for browser - any body can emulate valid request with curl or telnet. For true safety you need use dynamic generated pages with dynamic generated links.

You do not need to create the variable $invalid_referer as this is set by the nginx module.

Comment: I know nothing about nginx but don't you have to define the var $invalid_referer somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelRogers it's being set by the referer module

Comment: this is a good solution, but i think something may have changed. Instead of `deny all;` which throws an error, I used `return 403;` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you nginx powered development instances are showing up in Google search results, there is a quick and easy way to prevent search engines from crawling your site. Add the following line to the location block of your virtualhost configuration file for the block that you want to prevent crawling.

```
add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply deny access to any folder or file just by putting these lines with your folders' name

```
location ~ /(no_access_folder|folder_2)
{
     deny all;
     return 403;
}
```

Comment: But it also restricts the request made by the web application.

Comment: Is there any way, with which i can play videos in the website, but also restrict the direct access to them ?

Comment: @vivekascoder It is asked in question prevent direct access. So, it will block direct access to files but instead a developer can access and route the request with php and htaccess.

Comment: @vivekascoder yes you can do it with PHP or Node etc. You can route request and send custom response with php carrying your video in chunk or bulk