# How to hide direct access of your video/images file in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I am using Nginx Server. I have some images and video in `/video` directory. I am using these video and images into my site, but I want to show an 403 error, if someone try to access them directly like this examples shows:

http://xysz.com/video/abc.png

I know it's possible in Apache by changing the .htaccess config, but not sure how to do the same in Nginx. How can I achieve this with Nginx?

Comment: Isn't that how the consumers of your site are going to access it (via the browser)?

Comment: How do you achieve this with Apache?

Comment: @BradWerth yes they will access it through browser.

Comment: @Robin we can do it in Apache like,
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?dadaas.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?dadaas.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4|png|jpeg)$ - [F]

Comment: @Purushottam so check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591712/nginx-prevent-direct-access-to-static-files

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name xysz.com;
root /var/www/xysz.com/html ;
location /assets/ {
    valid_referers xysz.com/ xysz.com/video/index.html;
    if $invalid_referer {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Opposite question.  How do I still get access to the videos that are configured this way?